# How to insert basemaps in cartodb.js?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I'm desperately trying to swap out my basemap in cartodb.js.

Here's the snippet of code, the part I switched out successfully with some basemaps is in bold:
L.tileLayer('**https://dnv9my2eseobd.cloudfront.net/v3/cartodb.map-4xtxp73f/{z}/{x}/{y}.png**'

When I inspect element or go here, I get a wide variety of options, like so:
http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

For example, this works:
L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'

But this doesn't:

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.{base}.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/{type}/{mapID}/hybrid.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/{size}/{format}?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&lg={language}'

How do I swap out this code??

Answer (score 1):

The basemap that doesn't work, is one from here.com.
It is not accessible without registration so you first need to create an account at here.com and then register an app. Then you get an specific app_id and app_code with which you can replace the place holders in the template url.

Find general information regarding this topic at the [Here.com FAQ](https://developer.here.com/faqs#access-control)